# Keyboard / keymap problems with Xubuntu 12.04 + NX nomachine

Tags: keyboard, xubuntu, xfce, xmodmap, nx

I'm running NX client on my Macbook Pro to connect to a Xubuntu 12.04 desktop at work.  I have configured NX client to start up a console upon connection.  I am able to connect to my remote linux machine and I get a simple xterm console.

However, when I run `xfce4-session`, half my keys no longer work.  For example, when I launch a terminal, I typing a, s, or d works, but if type w, e, r, or t, the cursor just blinks.  If I ctrl-C out of xfce4-session, all the keys work fine in my xterm console.

If I run `xev`, this is the output for when I hit a key that works:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
root 0x373, subw 0x0, time 170160781, (-45,-21), root:(824,429),
state 0x4, keycode 16 (keysym 0x63, c), same_screen YES,
XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (03) ""
XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
root 0x373, subw 0x0, time 170160781, (-45,-21), root:(824,429),
state 0x4, keycode 67 (keysym 0xffe3, Control_L), same_screen YES,
XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 63
XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
XFilterEvent returns: False
```

but when I hit a key that doesn't work:

```
FocusOut event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
mode NotifyGrab, detail NotifyAncestor

FocusIn event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x2e00001,
mode NotifyUngrab, detail NotifyAncestor

KeymapNotify event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
       0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

Any ideas on what I can do to troubleshoot this issue?  Googling around offered a few suggestions (like playing with xmodmap) but nothing seemed to work.

Also, one thing worth mentioning is that I do not have any keyboard issues when remoting into a different Ubuntu 10 box via NX.

Answer (score 1):

Check the "**Application Shortcuts**" under Settings -> Keyboard.

Comment: You can make this answer better by editing your answer to provide more information and clarity.